# C# discord bot not working

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I can't start any bots and I'm just getting this error:

> Discord.Net.WebSocketException: 'Received close code 4012: Requested gateway version is no longer supported or invalid'

Is it because I need to update to 1.0+?

How do I know the version is the root cause and is upgrading the only option I have?

Comment: Can someone please just help me I've been working on that stuff for ages and I don't want to loose it.

Comment: you already have the error, there is nothing we can do beyond that because we have nothing more than what you gave us, your error is: **Requested gateway version is no longer supported or invalid**

Comment: This it looks like that, yes, upgrading is your only option.

Answer (score 2):

Discord.NET v0.9 uses version 5 of Discord API, which was discontinued today. All bots using Discord.NET v0.9 are no longer working.

Only solution is to upgrade to Discord.NET v1.0 wich uses the newest API version.